# how to check if a checkbox is checked in django template

Tags: django, forms, templates, checkbox

I need to check that if a checkbox is checked in django template and if False open up some other fields.
I already tried something like:

```
{% if 'closed' in 'is_closed %}
```

but they are always True and no matter if the checkbox is checked or not
so this is my checkbox properties in template

```
<input type="checkbox" name="is_closed" value="closed">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `checked` property by html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="is_closed" value="closed" {% if 'closed' in 'is_closed %} checked {% else %} '' {% endif %}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check form.field.value: `{% if form.checkbox_field.value %}`