# How to check a check box is checked with if statement in django template

Tags: python, html, django

I am making a registration form where I want that until the user checks the checkbox to accept the terms and conditions the registration(submit) button must be disabled. When the users check the box the button is enabled.

**This is the check box**

```
<label for="agree"><input type="checkbox" id="agree" name="agree" value="checked"><span style="color: springgreen;">I AGREE, to the terms and conditions.</span></label><br>
```

**and this is the button to be in conditions**

```
<input type="submit" value="REGISTER" >
```

Comment: read this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683728/how-to-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-django-template

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714763/django-check-if-checkbox-is-selected#:~:text=Then%20in%20your%20view%2C%20you,POST%22%3A%20display_type%20%3D%20request. This has already been discussed here.
Refer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sir if you want to make the registration of the user in the Django then make the custom user form for it.

but another temporary solution is this that just add the

```
<input type="checkbox" id="agree" name="agree" value="checked" required>
```

but add the required at the end but insert this line in the form section

but there is a problem there is not entry in the database that use had checked it not
but yes user was not able to sign in till he doesn't checked

and if you want to do it in the profestional way then make custom user
with the boolfield
there is the refrence link
https://www.fomfus.com/articles/how-to-use-email-as-username-for-django-authentication-removing-the-username/

this is just a sample link
s

Comment: Thank you sir, I will connect the data base later, I just wanted the disbale enable toggle to happen in the front end